# Read annotation data with Umlaut using iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext7

I am using iText to read the author and subject from stamp annotations.
If the annotation author includes non-ASCII characters (e.g. "äüö"), they are read as follows:

> Anton M�ller

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

namespace iText7Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Stream inputStream = File.OpenRead(@"Stamp_Anton_Mueller.pdf");

            PdfDocument annoPdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(inputStream));

            for (int iPage = 1; iPage <= annoPdf.GetNumberOfPages(); iPage++)
            {
                PdfPage annoPage = annoPdf.GetPage(iPage);
                var annotations = annoPage.GetAnnotations();

                foreach (var annot in annotations)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annoDict = annot.GetPdfObject();

                    if ("/Stamp" != annoDict.Get(PdfName.IT, true)?.ToString())
                        continue;

                    var subject = annoDict.Get(PdfName.Subj, true);
                    var author = annoDict.Get(PdfName.T); // this reads "Anton M�ller"
                    var creationDate = annoDict.Get(PdfName.CreationDate, false);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nAuthor of Stamp_Anton_Mueller.pdf: {0}", author); // this writes: "Author of Stamp_Anton_Mueller.pdf: Anton M?ller"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

If I simply load the inputStream into a string, the resulting string has the same � issues.

```
string myPdfString = new StreamReader(inputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

However, if I set the Encoding parameter of the StreamReader, the Umlaut is shown correctly.

```
string encodedPdfString = new StreamReader(inputStream, Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
```

I did not see any option to choose Encoding for the PdfReader

Sample PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_bs47kSkITX1SdDYllVBQPhRP4D3xUAw/view

Comment: Please share an example PDF to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you, I have added a sample PDF document.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue; I ran your code with `inputStream` being initialized as `File.OpenRead(@"Stamp_Anton_Mueller.pdf")` and with an additional `Console.WriteLine("\nAuthor of Stamp_Anton_Mueller.pdf: {0}", author);` at the end, and the output was ["Author of Stamp_Anton_Mueller.pdf: Anton Müller"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dBLH.png). Thus, either already your `properties.ListItem.File.OpenBinaryStream()` is broken or you handle the variable `author` incorrectly in further code. Or there is something special in your general setup.

Comment: I updated my code to use a new console application (.Net Framework 4.6.1, itext,kernel 7.1.8.0) and `File.OpenRead`. The input stream itself contains this in the second line: `%����`, which I assume is `%âãÏÓ` for you (tested using `new StreamReader(inputStream).ReadToEnd();`). So it is an issue with either the stream or the StreamReader/PdfReader, though I do not know why my code functions differently from yours, apart from maybe me working on a German Windows.

Comment: Just to be sure, please also output a hex dump of the string (e.g. using `foreach (byte aByte in author.ToString())
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0:X2} ", aByte);
                    }`). What do you get?

Comment: The result is: `41 6E 74 6F 6E 20 4D FD 6C 6C 65 72`

Comment: That *really* is weird, when I run the code, I get a `FC` where you have the `FD`, and that's the 'ü', so this is not merely a limitation of the console font in question but you really get something different... And I just also tested on a German Windows 10.. Do you have any special, non-standard character set settings?